# i spilled a sweet drink on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Right now I'm using on-screen keyboard. Yesterday I spilled a sweet drink onto my keyboard so I cleaned up the liquid that didn't go in the keyboard with a damp towel. I thought I fixed it so I continued what I was doing. The next day, I couldn't type anything. if I typed the letter "s" it would come as "[/s" what do i do now? I tried searching it up what to do, but all of  them are about as soon as it happened. I found one that told me to shake it, but nothing came out. The keyboard is a logitech K360.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219053/no-sound-speakers-jack-microphones-dead-after-spilling-water [doesn't make any difference if it's Mac or PC… the overall result is going to be the same.]

Answer (score 0):

Drinks that are sweet contain sugar which is sticky. The substance has stuck to the keys.

The only option now is to replace the keyboard. It cannot now be cleaned or fixed.

Comment: You can try unplugging it, removing batteries, completely immersing the keyboard in distilled water, rinse and repeat a few times, and leaving it to dry in a warm place with moving air for a week or so. This *might* work -- if electrolytic corrosion from leaving in batteries has not destroyed traces and switch contacts.

Comment: I'd cut your losses & just bin it - rinse & pray is a bit optimistic after a day in fizzy pop ;)